# How to change the slider color in Google MDL Lite

Tags: slider, material-design-lite

I need change the slider color in Google MDL Lite.

http://getmdl.io/components/index.html#sliders-section

The colors of the lines on the left and right of the circle are changing, but the circle is staying blue.

Any ideas.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

At first, for customizing colors there is perfect [Customizer](http://getmdl.io/customize/index.html) and it will do what you need.

But answer for your question are these lines (rather test it in all browsers):

```
.mdl-slider {
    &:active::-webkit-slider-thumb,
    &::-webkit-slider-thumb {
        background: $your-color !important;
    }

    &:active::-moz-range-thumb,
    &::-moz-range-thumb {
        background: $your-color !important;
    }

    &:active::-ms-thumb,
    &::-ms-thumb {
        background: $your-color !important;
    }
}
```

However, there are focus color and other fixes for IE. So if you want to be 100% sure, copy [this file with slider style](https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/blob/master/src/slider/_slider.scss) and change color variables ($range-color, $range-bg-color, $range-faded-color etc.) by your requirements. Or use first mentioned solution.

Comment: Can you tell me a way to set these colors dynamically through Javascript/jQuery?